# Where I can post a survey on backend development?

Tags: moderators, user-behavior

I'm doing research on backend development for a product I'm working on.

I would like to know where I can ask developers to take my survey on StackEchange. I'm looking for a good topic without looking like a spammer.

Thank you,

Answer (score -2):

An option would be to take your survey on [Stack Overflow site](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Stack Overflow is a large community of developers where you can find expertise in various programming and development-related topics.

You should create a survey online and provide a link within the body of your question.
Make sure that it will be easily accessible for users who are interested in participating.

Hope that helps

Alexios Valonasis

Comment: If you did this, your question would be closed as spam within minutes.  SO is for specific questions about programming issues.  Posting on SO's meta site wouldn't work either.